# Cocoapods podspec issue

Tags: static-libraries, xcode5, cocoapods

I've been in the process of refactoring some code and have created a static library that I'm now using in a framework that is used in a few apps.  I'm using cocoapods and am having trouble properly integrating my new static library into the podspec.

I'm finding that builds are failing because the static library is missing from the build.  If I manually add the static library to the final app, the framework and app work fine.  A build team generates the final releases of the apps, and because of this I've only been responsible for update the podspec for the framework only.

Is it possible for me to modify the pod spec to set the static library as a linked library that shows up under build phases of the final app?

UPDATE:

When adding the static lib to the framework.library attribute of my sub spec I'm getting `library not found for -lMyStaticLib`

SUBSPEC FOR REFERENCE:

```
  s.subspec 'MyStaticLibrary' do |msl|
    mss.source_files = 'FrameworkSource/My-Static-Library/*.{h,a}'
    msl.library = 'MyStaticLib'
    msl.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(SRCROOT)/Pods/My-Framework-Name/FrameworkSource/My-Static-Library"/**', 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(SRCROOT)/Pods/My-Framework-Name/FrameworkSource/My-Static-Library"/**' }
    #msl.frameworks =  'MyStaticLib'
  end
```

UPDATE 2:
I changed the attribute to `msl.vendored_libraries = 'MyStaticLib'` Also validated paths in podspec.  Everything 'seems' to check out.  I'm still getting build errors.
When I built for a device (I get same error but for i386 when I build for simulator):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyStaticLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyFramework(FileInFramework.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also verified again that if I just go to the app's build phases and traverse the Pods folders and manually add the MyStaticLibrary.a file to the project it builds without issue.

Comment: Still no fix for that? I'm running into a similar problem and would appreciate your wisdom in case you managed to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely add the framework in your podspec. Check out the [wiki entry on the Podspec format.](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/The-podspec-format#chained-attributes)

---

**Edit:** Ah, what you're looking for is `vendored_frameworks` or `vendored_libraries` which was added in [0.23.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0230rc1). Looks like those haven't been added to the wiki yet. Will update that now!

Comment: I think the link you meant was https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/The-podspec-format  Yours links to Steelcase ;-)  I updated my post with more info.

Comment: I've updated my post with more info.  Now i'm getting undefined architecture errors.  It's as if the project sees the library but cannot access anything in it.

Answer (score 5):

Try renaming your `MyStaticLib.a` file to `libMyStaticLib.a`. I was also getting the `library not found for -lMyStaticLib` error and fixed it by adding a `lib` prefix to the filename.

Answer (score 3):

For the error `Library not found for -lxxxxxxx`, if you static library name is `MyStaticLib.a`, try renaming to `libMyStaticLib.a` and put it in `perserve_paths` property so that your static library won't be removed after being downloaded:

```
msl.libraries = 'MyStaticLib'
msl.perserve_paths = 'libMyStaticLib.a'
```

Then, go to your project's build setting: to make sure you have the parameter `-lMyStaticLib` in 'Other Linker Flags'.

For the ARM and i386 architecture issues, ARM means iOS device, and i386 means simulator, better to make your static library **universal**, then it will work on both architectures.

Comment: Why do I need ``Other Linker Flags``? Isn't it sufficient to put it in ``LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS``?

Answer (score 2):

change the:

msl.vendored_libraries = 'MyStaticLib'

to:

msl.vendored_libraries = 'FrameworkSource/My-Static-Library/libMyStaticLib.a'

and cocoapods will add a search path.